# Multidimension arrays in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have created a multidimensional array

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 10
        [2] => 12
        [3] => 13
        [4] => 14
        [5] => 19
        [6] => 21
        [7] => 26
        [8] => 31
     )

   [1] => Array
     (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 290
        [2] => 852
        [3] => 9
        [4] => 896
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 0
        [8] => 0
     )

 )
```

I need to get the values 9, 10, 12, 13, 14,19,21,26,31 and match them with values 0, 290, 852, 9,890,0,0,0,0. These numbers are produced dynamical so more numbers are be generated

I have tried various ways to get it done using foreach loop and i also want to sort them using the second numbers in descending order, please help

I mean that they appear like this

- 9    0
- 10   290
- 12   852
- 13   9
- 14   890
- 19   0
- 21   0
- 26   0
- 31   0

when i print them so that i can sort them in descending order using the second column

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Are you trying for specific matches or are you looking for a general method? Also, do you mean you want to set array elements equal to one another? For example $array[0][0] = $array[1][0];

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like this,

```
$res = array();
$l1 = count($src[0]);
$l2 = count($src[1]);

if($l1 == $l2){

  for($i = 0; $i < $l1; $i++){
    $res[$src[0][$i] + ''] = $src[1][$i];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are asking but this may helps you

to get common values in both arrays use array_intersect

```
$abc = array_intersect($array[0], $array[1]);
```

and to get the differences in those arrays use array_diff

```
$abc= array_diff($array[0], $array[1]);
```